# Airline Change of Equipment Code

Tags: airlines, etihad

I booked two return business class tickets April 2015 Manchester / Bangkok via a flight/holiday centre for travel commencing 27th January 2016 . All flights were on Etihad Airlines with Etihad flight numbers. Today by pure chance I rang my agent to check prebooked  seat nos and all my seat allocation had been changed. Also I then noticed that the flight from Bangkok was not Etihad but Jet Airways which I believe is owned by Etihad . Also the business class seats are 49 inches in pitch as opposed to Eithad which are 73 inches in pitch. My agent never informed me of this change . I would not of booked this journey knowing that Jet Airways were part of my journey . I was offered an alternative homeward flight on Etihad with a 12 hour connection wait . Also I could change to another airline for an extra fee of £850 . If I had been aware that Eithad could downgrade me to a lesser flight I would not of booked it in the first place. Obviously not a lot I can do about it now. Can anyone advise me in any way on this problem. Even the agent was unaware that Etihad had changed planes and airlines. Also a refund was not possible .

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the company directly? They might offer a better solution if they have one.

Comment: Yes I have rang Etihad and they can not help as the ticket was booked through an agent . Thanks for your comment . Much appreciated .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I booked these tickets to fly Eihad with their business class seats. Jet Airaway are more of a budget airline and I didn't sign up for this. What comeback do Etihad have or do I just have to,put up with them selling tickets under false pretences . At no time was I informed of this change

Comment: Are you certain the flight was changed? Did the original itinerary mention that the flight was "operated by" a carrier other than Etihad? I strongly suspect your beef is with your agent, not with Etihad, either for not communicating the change or for failing to inform you of a codeshare in the first place. Etihad has an unusually large number of codeshare partnerships, but I would still find it unusual that an airline would rebook you on a partner when you'd originally been booked on its own "metal."

Comment: The original itinerary was an Etihad Flight . I have asked my agent when this was changed and they have failed to give me an answer. . The itinerary from my agent today still stated an Eithad Flight . I agree that this problem is with my agent which is a very large UK Company . Very bad management .

Comment: What was the original flight number, and what is the new one? Note that some of the AUH-BKK flights show up as "Operated by Etihad ON Jet Airways Configured Aircraft", which means they are indeed operated by Etihad, just that the aircraft is different from the usual ones. You probably won't have much recourse in case of equipment change. Note that for each of the flights with this aircraft, there's another one with a "regular" Etihad 777 a couple of hours before, which you should be able to connect to. Then there's just the issue of availability in your fare bucket on those flights.

Answer (score 1):

**It's unlikely there is anything you can do about this, other than booking a different flight.**

Changes to bookings happen all the time. Many are more serious than this, such as changes of departure day or even destination. In almost all cases the limit of the airline's liability is to offer you a full refund. I would have expected them to inform you, and you might have some cause for complaint there.

You really have only two options:

1. Claim a refund and book another flight. Presumably not practical.
2. Negotiate with the airline for some kind of price reduction. Based on the different spec of business class you have a good chance of this, especially if the cost of booking a business class fare on the new equipment is less than the equipment you originally booked on. You will probably have better results if you hold the possibility that you will switch to a different airline over them while you negotiate. If there is a higher class than business, maybe try for an upgrade to that class instead of a price reduction - something that might not cost the airline anything at all if there are spare first class seats. If you have to go through your agent, that shouldn't make any difference. Agents are often better placed to negotiate with airlines, and they want to keep your business more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I did ask my agent to request seats in the first class section. Eihad refused

Comment: I agree there is nothing I can really do about this . Obviously I will not fly Etihad again . Thankfully it is only one part of the journey .

Comment: Did you also try for a price reduction? If they refused everything, it probably means the plane is full after the change, and they are actually hoping some people will cancel.

Comment: I will try for a price reduction . It's worth a try

Comment: @BernadetteWhite Changes and cancellations are a risk of booking early on any airline; there is no cause for singling out Etihad, as it could easily have happened on Emirates or BA or Singapore just as easily.

Comment: Yes I agree that airlines do often change bookings. But they are not delivering the seat that i paid for . I have actually travelled this route for 20 years and yes there have been changes to my bookings.  But never has an airline downgraded my seating .Also bad communication from my agent who is a large operator in the UK

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer you also if you didn't wrote a clearly question .

Anyway airlines companies could change your airplane type , or can re-protect you without inform you ,the most important thing is that the carrier have to  guarantee you a same departure and arrival time and same class of the ticket that you booked .

That is about a general rule for all kind of travel services . For instance you can book a four star hotel , when you arrive to the hotel the hotel it's fully booked and it will ove you in an other hotel with similar feature ( in this case you cannot ask a refund ) .

Regarding some changes about seats reservation or airplane type , I think that your travel agent miss to read the message queue about changes in his GDS ( ex. Amadeus or Sabre ) .
If he is an Iata Agent and then he have a GDS system , I suppose that he didn't see this message , that we usually receive  .

Have you got a fare basis just to check the fare rules ?

Comment: I will check the fare basis . I have also written to the MD of the travel company